# Обновление информации

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<div Id="ajax_content">Контент, который должен незаметно обновляться</div>

function show() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#ajax_content").html(html);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    show();
    setInterval('show()', 1000);
});
```

В блоке `#ajax_content` обновляется не только информация, а полностью подгружается вся страница, на которой находится блок.

Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Добавьте код на стороне сервера.

Comment: А что делает show()? По идее в ajax не хватает параметра URL. Попробуйте html заменить на msg или что-то другое

Comment: @Денис Павлик Что вы имеете в виду (полностью подгружается вся страница, на которой находится блок.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял у тебя запрос выполняется каждую секунду после загрузки страницы.

```
<div Id="ajax_content">Контент, который должен незаметно обновляться</div>
```

Js:

```
$(function show() {  
   var id = "555";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",  //тип запросу "POST" или "GET"
  url: "ajax.php",  //куда отправляем запрос.
  data : {id : id}, //что отсылаем в нашем случае id.
  cache: false,

   success: function(rez) {
      $("#ajax_content").html(rez);
    }
 });

});


$(document).ready(function() {
     show();
    setInterval('show()', 1000);
});
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
    echo $id = $_POST['id'];    
?>
```

Comment: Что делает ajax.php? Покажите код. Вы передаете переменную id в скрипт ajax.php, но show() не получает эту переменную.

Comment: 555 в блоке `#ajax_content`  у тебя выводится или нет?

Comment: Да, а как передать ещё один id?

Comment: data : {id:id, id1:id1}